# playtika.testcontainers Error creating bean with name 'embeddedClickHouse'

Tags: java, spring, testcontainers, clickhouse-go

I am trying to run tests using playtika.testcontainers embedded-clickhouse, which used to work, but now I am getting `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext`, caused by `Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'embeddedClickHouse' defined in class path resource [com/playtika/test/clickhouse/EmbeddedClickHouseBootstrapConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.testcontainers.containers.ClickHouseContainer]: Factory method 'clickHouseContainer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/jpountz/lz4/LZ4Factory`.

Does anybody know if something was changed in the API?

Answer (score 0):

This issue might be fixed with https://github.com/PlaytikaOSS/testcontainers-spring-boot/pull/865.

In general, I would recommend using Testcontainers for Java directly on such cases.